# Discord.js Throw exception in .catch

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Because the discord doesn't support to delete messages older than 14 days. I want to create an exception to the error, when the bot is trying to delete old messages,**but the throw in .catch doesn't work** and i don't know why.

This is my code:

```
    try{
      message.channel.bulkDelete(200, false)
      .catch(error =>{
           throw 1;
      });
    message.channel.send(“Deleted 200 messages”);
    }catch(error){
     message.channel.send(“cant delete messages”);

    }
```

I know that i can do this `bulkDelete(200, true)` but that wont throw exception when it is trying to delete the old messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this

```
try {
  await message.channel.bulkDelete(100, false);
  message.channel.send("Deleted 100 messages");
} catch(error) {
  message.channel.send("Can't delete messages");
}
```

bulkDelete is a promise so you have to put it in an async function and await it or use the .then syntax. Also it can delete only 100 messages and returns an error with more.

I'm not sure why you want to throw 1 when you get an error but if you need it you can put it in the catch statement after sending the message

Comment: In my code is user input (`message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1], false);`) and i don't won't to post it here, because it can be confusing.